# How to display time of video in Ember.js / Handlebars

Tags: ember.js

I am working on an application with HTML5 video where I have to display the current time of the `video` tag of my page in a seperate label.

I tried to define a property in my view which returns the formatted time of the video, something like

```
videoCounter: function() {
    return App.seconds2String(Math.floor(App.getCurrentVideoTime() + 0.5));
}.property().volatile()
```

which returns the current time of the video as mm:ss.

The function `App.getCurrentVideoTime()` gets the current time from the video element in the page (so it is not an Ember property and therefore an not be bound) like this:

```
getCurrentVideoTime: function() {
    var videoElement = document.getElementById('video');
    if (videoElement) {
        return Math.round(videoElement.currentTime * 10) / 10;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The handlebars view contains

```
<label id="videoCounter">{{view.videoCounter}}</label>
```

Unfortunately the value is not updated as the video plays, i. e. it displays `00:00` all the time.

How can i trigger an update for the computed property that is only dependent on the current time of the video tag?

I don't need high accuracy, the timer should only show the current time of the video in seconds.

Any ideas?

Thank you so much!

Thomas

Comment: What about binding the computed property on 'App.currentVideoTime' ?

Comment: Not sure you can do that since the value returned by App.getCurrentVideoTime() is not observed by Ember. Either you do it with a setInterval(), or you some how setup an observer on the current time.

Comment: If App.currentVideoTime is a computed property based on the current time, binding videoCounter on App.currentVideoTime should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not obvious from the code you've stated whether you are using a custom view, but I would create a custom `Video` view and bind to the `timeupdate` event, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/fzNMb/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{view App.Video width="400px" controllerBinding="App.videoController"}}
    {{App.videoController.currentTimeFormatted}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.Video = Ember.View.extend({
    srcBinding: 'controller.src',
    controls: true,
    tagName: 'video',
    attributeBindings: 'src controls width height'.w(),

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().on("timeupdate", {
            element: this
        }, this.timeupdateDidChange);
    },

    timeupdateDidChange: function(evt) {
        var video = evt.data.element;
        var currentTime = evt.target.currentTime;
        video.setPath('controller.currentTime', currentTime);
    }
});​
```

Comment: Great, that was exactly what i was looking for! I'm not using a custom view for the video at the moment, but I will introduce one in order to adapt this solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wow, the jsfiddle makes chromium crash (version 18.0.1025.151). Anyway, I was not aware of the 'timeupdate' event. One more time, Thx Clemens :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I said and the use of setInterval mentioned by @Zack

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/xgqkL/

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({

          // computed property based on currentTime change
          videoCounter: function(){
              return this.get('currentTime');            
          }.property('currentTime'),

          currentTime: 0
});

// increment currentTime property every second
setInterval(function(){
    App.incrementProperty('currentTime');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that `currentTime` is not a property but just the current time of the HTML video element in the page, so i can not bind it to anything. It just changes as the video plays. I added this to my question. I'll try to read the time from the video and push it into a property with setInterval().